# Can someone help me to give some hints? Left Hilbert-$C_0(T,K(H))$ module $C_0(T,H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I tried to prove example 3.4 from the book *Morita Equivalence and Continuous-Trace C$^*$-Algebras*  by Iain Raeburn and Dana P. Williams, but I get uneasy with notations and ideas. Let me restate my assumption about this example.

> Suppose that $T$ is locally compact Hausdorff space and that $H$ is a complex Hilbert space. Then
>   $$X:=C_0(T,H)=\left\{ x:T\rightarrow H: x \:continuous,t\rightarrow \left\| x(t)\right\|\in C_0(T)\right\}$$
>   complex vector space and
>   $$A:=C_0(T,K(H))=\left\{ f:T\rightarrow K(H): f \:continuous,t\mapsto \left\| x(t)\right\|\in C_0(T) \right\}$$
>   C*-algebra. Then $C_0(T,H)$ is left Hilbert-$C_0(T,K(H))$ module under this operation:
>   $$f\bullet x(t)=f(t)(x(t))$$
>   $$_A \left\langle x,y \right\rangle (t)=x(t) \otimes \bar{y(t)} $$
>   for $x,y\in C_0(T,H)$ and $f\in C_0(T,K(H))$.

My questions are:

1. Is $\otimes$ here related to tensor product? What kind of tensor product?
2. Is $t\rightarrow \left\| x(t)\right\|\in C_0(T)$ and $t\mapsto \left\| x(t)\right\|\in C_0(T)$ different?
3. Is norm for $_A\left\| x(t) \right\|$ a sup-norm?

Comment: I think your definition of $A$ should read $f:T \to K(H)$ continuous such that $t \mapsto \|f(t)\| \in C_0(T)$.

Comment: It fixed, thanks @PrahladVaidyanathan :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For two vectors $x,y\in H$, the notation $x\otimes y$ is frequently used to denote the rank-one operator $z\longmapsto \langle z,y\rangle x$. It is related to tensor products, but not in the obvious way: it is seeing $x\otimes y$ as an element of $H\otimes H^*$ (most often, no one pays attention to this and just uses the notation).
2. I think it is just a typo, it should have been $\longmapsto $ in both cases.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by  $_A\|x(t)\|$. The elements of the Hilbert module are functions $T\to H$. And $_A\langle x,y\rangle$ is a function $T\to K(H)$. In a Hilbert module you often construct a norm by taking the square root of the norm in $A$, i.e.
   $$
   \|x\|:=\|_A\langle x,x\rangle\|_A^{1/2}.
   $$
   In this case $A$ is a function algebra, so its norm is a sup norm. So 
   $$
   \|x\|=\sup\{|_A\langle x,x\rangle (t)|^{1/2}:\ t\in T\}
   $$

Comment: I use $_A\left\| x \right\|$ (norm on left pre-Hilbert-C* module) just to differ it from $\left\| x \right\| _A$ (norm on right pre-Hilbert-C* module), because the book says nothing about left Hilbert-C* module. I want to ask more about (2). Is $t\mapsto \left\| x(t) \right\| \in C_0(T)$ means that norm on $X$ and $A$ are take values (or similar?) to norm on $C_0(T)$  ?

Comment: I write $\|\cdot\|_A$ to denote the norm on $A$. As for $t\longmapsto\|x(t)\|$, I don't understand what you asking.

Comment: I want to ask about what $t\mapsto \left\| x(t) \right\| \in C_0(T)$ means. That part still not clear for me.

Comment: That's a (common, and clear when you get used to it) notation for the function $f (t)=\|x (t)\|$. Every time you have a rule that assigns a number to each point in $T $, you can ask yourself whether that assignment is continuous, and whether it vanishes at infinity.